# Filtering Pandas data frame based on multiple user input vales

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code to select a single row in a dataframe:

```
products_df1_final = (products_df1.loc[products_df1['uuid'] == "790a06bf-91a5- 
487e-988e-2c8294bd4355"])
products_df1_final
```

However, I can't seem to make it work when the user inputs more than one 'uuid' field value to filter.  I would like to create a little code to ask the user to input the various 'uuid' field values so as to create a dataframe with just the user selected 'uuid' rows.

The following code doesn't work:

```
n = str(input('Enter product numbers:')) products_df1_final =
(products_df1.loc[products_df1['uuid'] == 'n'])
display(products_df1_final[['title','uuid','ingestiondate','size']])
```

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilized a list comprehension approach.

```
# Directory to place files
download_directory = (r"C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Land Suitability Model\Layers\Sentinel\Sentinel RST\Downloads")

print("Enter Two UUID tiles for download:")

n = input('Enter product number:')
m = input('Enter another product number:')
#products_df1_final = products_df1[[x == ["n", "m"]] for x in products_df1.uuid
products_df1_final = products_df1[products_df1.uuid.isin([n, m])]
products_df1_final

# Sentinel Products to download 
api.download_all(products_df1_final.index, checksum=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the way you used your input variable `n`. If you quote it, as you did, it is going to be treated as a string `"n"` instead of the variable name.

Another way is how the input looks like. If it is a string, it won't work. You have to use a list. An example could be:

```
n = str(input('Enter product number:')) 
m = str(input('Enter another product number:')) 
products_df1_final = (products_df1.loc[products_df1['uuid'] == [n, m]])
```

Or, to extend it to an actual list variable `product_names`:

```
product_names = []
pname = None
while pname != '':
    pname = str(input('Enter product number:'))
    if pname != '':
         product_names.append(pname)   

products_df1_final = (products_df1.loc[products_df1['uuid'] == product_names])
```

Comment: I like the first one because it is simple and I can't download more than 2 at a time. 
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (9,), (2,)) for both.
--> 224                 "Lengths must match to compare", lvalues.shape, rvalues.shape
    225             )
    226

Comment: What is your data exactly? Please add a few rows of your dataframe.

Comment: I just added a screenshot for you to look at.